# How I can make click for button if I have LinearLayout with own click event which include the button

Tags: java, android, android-layout

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_image" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="something" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>


btn1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
btn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

I can not click on the button. Always called click on LinearLayout.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn:
// set something parametr
        break;
    case R.id.btn1:
// go to activity
        break;
    }   

}
```

Comment: is there any special requirement for click event on Linear layout ? Show your onClick() Method Code.

Comment: have you ever seen a user interface with a button inside another button? me neither, maybe you should not do it this way and have non-overlapping clicking area.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work for me like this,

Your xml file,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="something" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And your Activity class,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
     LinearLayout  btn1 =null;
     Button     btn =null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           btn1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
           btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
           btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
           btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(v==btn)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "btn clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if(v==btn1)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "btn1 clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can still differentiate in the onclick method:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v.getId() == R.id.btn1)
    {
        // Linear was clicked
    }
    else if (v.getId() == R.id.btn){
        // Button was clicked
    }

}
```

But you should still remove the button from the linear

Answer (score 0):

put clickable true in  tag..

file **android:clickable="true"**

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" android:onClick="" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/actionbar_background" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="something" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

...................................

```
btn1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.btn1);

btn1.setOnClickListener(this);

btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

btn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

...................................

```
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {

      switch (v.getId()) {
      case R.id.btn:
         // set something parametr
       break;
     case R.id.btn1:
         // go to activity
       break;
    }   

   }
```